# "Computed" property in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, properties

Folks, I'm in the middle of "learning by doing" in Angular 6 & 7, and I came across this issue a number of times.

Imagine I have a class/interface/type - e.g. `Person` - with a few properties, that are returned by a Web API call - something like this:

```
export interface Person {
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    JobTitle: string;
    // so other properties - not relevant to this question
}
```

What I'd like to be able to is show the **full name** (e.g. "FirstName + [Space] + LastName") in e.g. an Angular grid (AG-Grid) or someplace else - where I **cannot** use a concat expression or anything, but I need to refer to a single property on the class/interface/type.

In C#, I would just create a property

```
string FullName { get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; } }
```

and be done with it - but how can I do this in Typescript?? From what I've been reading and researching, this seems to be **unsupported** - really?!?!!? How can that be??? Seems like such a simple and often-used operation - what's the reason this doesn't exist in Typescript?? Or does it exist - and I just haven't found the way to do this in TS?

Comment: Have a look at the Accessors section [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html). I think a getter (get) might do what you need.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If it's an interface then there's no syntax, because all properties in JavaScript can have getter/setter functions instead of being exposed fields. It's an implementation concern.

BTW members in TypeScript use `camelCase` not `TitleCase`:

```
export interface Person {
    // get + set:
    firstName: string;
    lastName : string;
    jobTitle : string;

    // get-only:
    readonly fullName : string;
}

class SimplePerson implements Person {

    public firstName: string; // value-property (“field”)
    public lastName: string;
    public jobTitle: string;

    get fullName(): string { // read-only property with getter function (this is not the same thing as a “function-property”)
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

---

<sub>I note that it is confusing that TypeScript's designers chose to use the keyword `readonly` to denote "readable" properties in an interface when it doesn't actually prohibit an implementation from also having a property setter - I would have preferred the syntax to be something like `readable fullName: string;` and `readwrite fullName: string;` - C#/.NET has the same problem: the `IReadOnlyList<T>` interface does not mean implementations have to be immutable.</sub>

Comment: It's also probably a good idea to mark `fullName` as readonly, since otherwise it might be assumed that it is get/set, e.g. `readonly fullName: string;` in your interface

Comment: Yes, it works when I create instance of SimplePerson via constructor. But what should I do if I receive it from http request? In that case property fullName is undefined :(

Comment: @mli You'll need to manually add the property to each object you process using `Object.defineProperty`.

Answer (score 11):

Javascript supports `get` and `set` when defining a property (mostly using `Object.defineProperty`).

Apparently there's an handy syntax for it in typescript (for classes) :

```
class MyClass{
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  get fullName(){
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }
}
```

Regarding interfaces, I'm not sure such a thing is possible since their sole purpose is data description not implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You can also define `get`ters and `set`ters in JavaScript.

Try this in your Component Class:

```
person: Person;
...
// You got the person Object from your Backend API.
...
// Now
get fullName() { 
  return `${this.person.firstName} ${this.person.lastName}`; 
}
```

And then in your Template:

Simply use `fullName` like this:

```
<p>{{ fullName }}</p>
```

Comment: However, this is only accessible for that component.  If we need global computed variable we have to go with Class instead of Interface. correct me, if I am wrong..